# Manifolds in Hilbert Space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, differential-geometry

I am recently going through Quantum Mechanics through R.Shankars Principles of Quantum Mechanics. An Function in an infinite-dimensional vector space is actually driving me crazy (I am sorry about my language, but ....). I read that the $x$ or the $p$ basis are just manifolds in Hilbert space. Can anyone please explain what his means. Also can I imagine the different basis such as the momentum basis and x-basis in the same way as:
$$|p_1\rangle = \alpha_1|x_1\rangle +...+\alpha_n|x_n\rangle+...+\alpha_{\infty}|x_{\infty}\rangle$$
or this approach just fails? How can I imagine what a hilbert space is and what are the manifold? I am new to geometry, So please answer accordingly.

Comment: *"I read that the x or the p basis are just manifolds in Hilbert space."* - where did you read that?

Comment: "I read that the $x$ or the $p$ basis are just manifolds in Hilbert space." - This is just as meaningless as saying that knives and forks are gyms in the kitchen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set of $|x,y,z\rangle$ basis vectors pretty much by definition correspond exactly 1 to 1 with position vectors in $\mathbb R^3$, since each position should have a quantum state to represent the system existing there. This means many things associated with 3D Euclidean space hold for the vector space spanned by the $|x,y,z\rangle$ basis. Most relevant to this is question that it can be fully covered by a coordinate systems with differentiable transition maps (coordinate transformations), making it a differentiable manifold. This allows you to take derivatives of the basis vectors (parameterized by their $\hat X,\hat Y,\hat Z$ operator eigenvalues) which can be seen from something like:
$$\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\langle x,y,z|\right)|\psi\rangle = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\psi(x,y,z)$$

The expansion $|p_1\rangle = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\alpha_n|x_n\rangle$ is not quite right. The position basis is *continuous*, meaning it has an uncountably infinite number of elements. Therefore to expand a vector in this basis you need to integrate over $x$ with a continuous coefficient function rather than sum over a discrete index:
$$|p_1\rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\alpha(x)|x\rangle\mathrm dx$$